# Ansible Loops with Lists

Tags: loops, ansible, nested

I am looking for some help to parse the nested list date in the ansible role/playbook.

```
Below is what I am trying to acheive
For each policyID in variable file
    get name, srcint, dstint, action in each policyid
    get all srcaddr from varfile ( example it may have 5 entries)
    get all dstaddr from varfile ( example it may have 2 entries)
    get all service from varfile  ( example it may have 1 or 5 entries)
If there are 5 policy IDs, then 5 policies with above details will be created
folder structure
├── ansible.cfg
├── host_vars
│   ├── FWUKDC001
│   │   └── var.yml
│   └── [template]
│       └── var.yml
├── main.yml
└── roles
    └── policy
        └── tasks
            ├── address.yml
            ├── main.yml
            ├── policy.yml
            └── service.yml
```

My variable file:

```yaml
   policy:
      - policyid:
          - name: "Internal->Internet1"
            action: "accept"
            srcintf: "Internal"
            dstintf: "Internet"
            srcaddr:  # policy[0].srcaddr
              - name: "n_10.0.10.0_24"  # policy[0].srcaddr[0].name
              - name: "n_10.0.20.0_24"  # policy[0].srcaddr[1].name
            dstaddr:
              - name: "n_8.8.8.8_32"
              - name: "n_7.8.8.8_32"
            service:
              - name: "TCP_8080"
              - name: "TCP_8081"
      - policyid:
         -  name: "Internal->Internet2"
            action: "accept"
            srcintf: "Internal"
            dstintf: "DMZ"
            srcaddr:
              - name: "n_10.0.10.0_24"
              - name: "n_10.0.20.0_24"
            dstaddr:
              - name: "n_172.16.0.0_24"
            service:
              - name: "TCP_8080"
              - name: "TCP_8081"
```

My role file:

```yaml
- name: Firewall Policy
  fortios_firewall_policy:
   state: "{{ operation }}"
   firewall_policy:
    policyid: "0"
    schedule: "always"
    nat: "disable"
    name: "{{item.0.name}}"
    action: "{{item.0.action}}"
    srcintf:
     - name: "{{item.0.srcintf}}"
    dstintf:
     - name: "{{item.0.dstintf}}"
    srcaddr:
     - name: "{{item.1.value}}"
    dstaddr:
     - name: "{{item.2.value}}"
    service:
     - name: "{{item.3.value}}"

  with_nested:
    - "{{ policy }}"
    - "{{ policy.srcaddr }}"
    - "{{ policy.dstaddr }}"
    - "{{ policy.service }}"
```

I am trying to get the values of variables from YAML file and use it in the role file but not able to find good documentation around it.
Not sure if `sub_elements` will do the job or normal loop, or `with_elements`.
Help would be apreciated

Comment: Can you describe the expected result and what differs from it? Where is you var file? How did you try to use it in your playbook/role? How exactly do you want to loop on those vars? If you tried something, what is the error you get? As is, you are basically asking us to guess what you want to do exactly. Regarding "good documentation", for a start => [Using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html), [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html). And I also suggest you read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to use the cartesian product of `srcaddr × dstaddr × service` to generate a series of policy actions. We can use the `set_fact` module to add a value to each policy that contains the appropriate data, and then using a `subelements` filter in a subsequent loop to actually render the policy tasks.

In the example below, I've wrapped everything in the `debug` module (because I don't have any way to test your use of the `fortios_firewall_policy` module), but the output should confirm (or not) that this is producing the correct results.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    policy:
      - policyid: "0"  # policy[0].policyid
        name: "Internal->Internet1"
        action: "accept"
        srcintf: "Internal"
        dstintf: "Internet"
        srcaddr:  # policy[0].srcaddr
          - name: "n_10.0.10.0_24"  # policy[0].srcaddr[0].name
          - name: "n_10.0.20.0_24"  # policy[0].srcaddr[1].name
        dstaddr:
          - name: "n_8.8.8.8_32"
          - name: "n_7.8.8.8_32"
        service:
          - name: "TCP_8080"
          - name: "TCP_8081"
      - policyid: "1"
        name: "Internal->Internet2"
        action: "accept"
        srcintf: "Internal"
        dstintf: "DMZ"
        srcaddr:
          - name: "n_10.0.10.0_24"
          - name: "n_10.0.20.0_24"
        dstaddr:
          - name: "n_172.16.0.0_24"
        service:
          - name: "TCP_8080"
          - name: "TCP_8081"
  tasks:
    # Here we're adding a "values" key to each entry in your "policy" list that
    # contains the cross product of srcaddr, dstaddr, and service.
    - set_fact:
        targets: >-
          {{
            targets + [
              item | combine({
                'policy': item,
                'values': item.srcaddr|product(item.dstaddr, item.service)|list
              })
            ]
          }}
      loop: "{{ policy }}"
      vars:
        targets: []

    # Now we can use the "values" key we created in the previous task with
    # the "subelements" filter:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - name: Firewall Policy
            fortios_firewall_policy:
              state: "foo"
              firewall_policy:
              policyid: "{{ item.0.policyid }}"
              schedule: "always"
              nat: "disable"
              name: "{{item.0.name}}"
              action: "{{item.0.action}}"
              srcintf:
                - name: "{{item.0.srcintf}}"
              dstintf:
                - name: "{{item.0.dstintf}}"
              srcaddr:
                - name: "{{item.1.0.name}}"
              dstaddr:
                - name: "{{item.1.1.name}}"
              service:
                - name: "{{item.1.2.name}}"
      loop: "{{ targets|subelements('values') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}-{{ item.1 }}"
```

This will generate as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'policyid': '0', 'name': 'Internal->Internet1', 'action': 'accept', 'srcintf': 'Internal', 'dstintf': 'Internet', 'srcaddr': [{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}], 'dstaddr': [{'name': 'n_8.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'n_7.8.8.8_32'}], 'service': [{'name': 'TCP_8080'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'policyid': '1', 'name': 'Internal->Internet2', 'action': 'accept', 'srcintf': 'Internal', 'dstintf': 'DMZ', 'srcaddr': [{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}], 'dstaddr': [{'name': 'n_172.16.0.0_24'}], 'service': [{'name': 'TCP_8080'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]})

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_8.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8080'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_8.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8080"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.10.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_8.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_8.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8081"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.10.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_7.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8080'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_7.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8080"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.10.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_7.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_7.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8081"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.10.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_8.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8080'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_8.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8080"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.20.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_8.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_8.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8081"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.20.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_7.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8080'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_7.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8080"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.20.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet1-[{'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_7.8.8.8_32'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_7.8.8.8_32"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internet"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet1",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "0",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8081"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.20.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet2-[{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_172.16.0.0_24'}, {'name': 'TCP_8080'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_172.16.0.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "DMZ"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet2",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "1",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8080"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.10.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet2-[{'name': 'n_10.0.10.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_172.16.0.0_24'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_172.16.0.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "DMZ"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet2",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "1",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8081"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.10.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet2-[{'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_172.16.0.0_24'}, {'name': 'TCP_8080'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_172.16.0.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "DMZ"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet2",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "1",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8080"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.20.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Internal->Internet2-[{'name': 'n_10.0.20.0_24'}, {'name': 'n_172.16.0.0_24'}, {'name': 'TCP_8081'}]) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "fortios_firewall_policy": {
                "action": "accept",
                "dstaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_172.16.0.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "dstintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "DMZ"
                    }
                ],
                "firewall_policy": null,
                "name": "Internal->Internet2",
                "nat": "disable",
                "policyid": "1",
                "schedule": "always",
                "service": [
                    {
                        "name": "TCP_8081"
                    }
                ],
                "srcaddr": [
                    {
                        "name": "n_10.0.20.0_24"
                    }
                ],
                "srcintf": [
                    {
                        "name": "Internal"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "foo"
            },
            "name": "Firewall Policy"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks, Larsks, let me test it,

Comment: Hi Larsks, I pasted the below code in my role file but getting error that policyid not found

Comment: The example I posted runs as written. You can see a complete run [here](https://asciinema.org/a/ziwji4nGuoD6jLeIu3wgAOjYS). If you're getting errors, either you're not running exactly the code I've posted here or there's some sort of weird version skew going on. What version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: Hi Larsks,  seems there were some formatting issue, after a few tries and adjusting the indent it is bit happy. I have two issues, seems the loop is running 8 times, though I want to run it only once per policy  ( policy ID 0 and 1 in this example). when I kept the var in same file there is no issues but when I moved the var to var file, I am getting error on. 8 loops ran and I got error that The error was: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'\n\n, probably it is trying to get name for some wrong key

Comment: Maybe update your question as @Zeitounator has requested, because it's not clear how you expect to map multiple values from your policy var (e.g. for `srcaddr`) into a single call of the `fortios_firewall_policy` module. The example you've show in your question isn't very specific.

Comment: @Zeitounator, I have added some info to the query, please let me know if you want me to add more

Answer (score -1):

You have nested lists that is a bit tedious. A simple example would be

e.g. if you YAML data file looks like that

```
dstaddr:
      - name: "n_8.8.8.8_32"
      - name: "n_7.8.8.8_32"
```

you could loop over that with

```
- name: load vars
  include_vars: "data.yml"

- name: with list of items looping
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_list: "{{ dstaddr}}"
```